# How can i set 24 hours interval in my code?

Tags: php, sql

```
    /**
     * Link countries stats
     */
    $link_countries = $this->Stat->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Stat.link_id' => $id),
        'fields' => array('Stat.country', 'COUNT(Stat.country) AS country_num'),
        'order' => array(
            'country_num' => 'desc'
        ),
        'group' => array('Stat.country'),
    ));
    $countries = Hash::combine($link_countries, '{n}.Stat.country', '{n}.0.country_num');
    $this->set('countries', $countries);

    /**
     * Link continents stats
     */
    $link_continents = $this->Stat->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Stat.link_id' => $id),
        'fields' => array('Stat.continent', 'COUNT(Stat.continent) AS continent_num'),
        'order' => array(
            'continent_num' => 'desc'
        ),
        'group' => array('Stat.continent'),
    ));
    $continents = Hash::combine($link_continents, '{n}.Stat.continent', '{n}.0.continent_num');
    $this->set('continents', $continents);
```

**like this**

```
  /**
     * Link stats for last 30 days
     */
    $linksStats = $this->Stat->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Stat.link_id' => $id,
            'Stat.created BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()'
        ),
        'fields' => array('DATE_FORMAT(Stat.created,"%d-%m-%Y") AS statDate', 'COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(Stat.created,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS statDateCount'),
        'order' => array(
            'Stat.created' => 'DESC'
        ),
        'group' => array('statDate'),
    ));
    $linksStats = Hash::combine($linksStats, '{n}.0.statDate', '{n}.0.statDateCount');
    $this->set('linksStats', $linksStats);
```

in this code their is 30 days intervel its ok but i want to set 24 hours intevel in  **Link countries stats** and **Link continents stats**

is there is any one who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INTERVAL 24 HOUR` instead `INTERVAL 30 DAY`. [More Details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
$linksStats = $this->Stat->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Stat.link_id' => $id,
            'Stat.created BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND NOW()'
        ),
        'fields' => array('DATE_FORMAT(Stat.created,"%d-%m-%Y") AS statDate', 'COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(Stat.created,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS statDateCount'),
        'order' => array(
            'Stat.created' => 'DESC'
        ),
        'group' => array('statDate'),
    ));
```

Comment: `code`
  /**
     * Link countries stats
     */
    $link_countries = $this->Stat->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Stat.link_id' => $id),
 'Stat.created BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND NOW()'
        ),
        'fields' => array('Stat.country', 'COUNT(Stat.country) AS country_num'),
        'order' => array(
            'country_num' => 'desc'
        ),
        'group' => array('Stat.country'),
    ));
    $countries = Hash::combine($link_countries, '{n}.Stat.country', '{n}.0.country_num');
    $this->set('countries', $countries); `code`

Comment: Sorry Not getting you ? is above code returning any error ? did you tried it ?

Comment: i want to add 24 hours intervel in country stats 
is that
this codeline will word ? 
`code`'Stat.created BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOURS) AND NOW()'
        ),`code`

Comment: just try it and let me know if you are getting any error? one more thing you can also use `INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: i want to count same ip click only once in 24 hours 
can u plz check my all code and suggest me where does i need to add INTERVAL ??? to count same ip click at once
[link](likerpubs.us/stats.txt)
check that txt link nd tell me plz

Comment: can u plz help me? in this case ?